# Grouping similarly to MySQLs GROUP BY

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset which looks somewhat like this;

```
email       minutes   date
aaa@aaa.com   40      10-01-18

aaa@aaa.com   60      10-01-18

bbb@bbb.com   10      10-01-18

bbb@bbb.com   40      10-02-18

ccc@ccc.com   60      10-02-18
```

I wish to group by email and filter for total minutes per date > 80. So on 10-01-18 aaa@aaa.com has >80 but bbb@bbb.com has not.

How can this kind of filtering be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a calculated field :

{FIXED [email], [date] : SUM([minutes])}

Place it on the filters shelf >> All values >> 80 trashhold >> Ok

Now right click new filter pill and select option Add to context (so filter'll be applied before other calculations)

Comment: Super useful! Thanks.